# Google App Engine and SSL Payment Page

Tags: ssl, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I have an app hosted on Google App Engine and I need to have a payment page that uses SSL. GAE only allows you to use SSL on their appspot domain but I want to keep it on my custom domain. Is it appropriate to host my payments page with a different hosting provider that allows SSL on my domain?

Answer (score 1):

> GAE only allows you to use SSL on their appspot domain

GAE now (2015) supports SSL for custom domains.

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/ssl

Answer (score 0):

You can do it, but you still need a secure way to deliver payments information to your app. I suppose [SDC](https://developers.google.com/secure-data-connector/docs/1.0/overview) fill fit for this purpose.